# Como quebrar a linha ao passar o tamanho da div?

Tags: html, css, css3

Estou com esse problema ao renderizar um texto sem espaçamento.

Como posso resolve-lo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste o seu código além da imagem, isso ajudará a identificar o problema.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Entendi que não há uma quebra de linha por não conter espaços. Use a propriedade `word-wrap` e defina o valor `break-word`, isso irá forçar uma quebra de linha assim que o texto atingir os limite da `div`.

## Veja.

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>
   Note:InternetExplorer9andearlierversionsdonosupportWeb Workers.
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sub>[CSS3 word-wrap Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)</sub>